# Start nodes or launchfiles as independent process from Python

Tags: ros-humble

I want to write a 'Execute' Node that is able to start new ROS Nodes or launchfiles as independent processes (i.e., the newly launched nodes are not killed when the 'Execute' Node is killed). Ideally, it would be interesting to use `LaunchService` for this to take advantage of using `LaunchDescription`.

Something like:

```py
class Execute(Node):
    def start_ros_node(self, node_dict):
        node = launch_ros.actions.Node(**node_dict)
        launch_service = LaunchService()
        launch_service.include_launch_description(LaunchDescription([node]))
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=launch_service.run, daemon=True)
        process.start()
        return process

node_dict = {
    'executable': sys.executable,
    'arguments': ['mock_lc_node.py'],
    'name': 'mock_node',
    'output': 'screen',
}
execute_node = Execute()
execute_node.start_ros_node(node_dict)
```

The above code doesn't work, I guess the new nodes are killed when the program calling it is killed.

I tried using `launch_service.run()` but it blocks the program execution, and it the nodes are also killed when the calling program is killed.

Any ideas?

Related:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/365863/ros2-launch-nodes-by-python-script/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/410041/ros2-launchservice-run-as-non-blocking/
- https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/724
- https://github.com/ros2/launch/pull/210

**EDIT:**
For now, I opted to use `subprocess` and run the new nodes as if I am running from the command line.

```py
def start_ros_node(node_dict):
    cmd = 'ros2 run '
    if 'package' in node_dict and 'executable' in node_dict:
        cmd += node_dict['package'] + ' '
        cmd += node_dict['executable']
        if 'name' in node_dict or 'parameters' in node_dict:
            cmd += ' --ros-args '
            if 'name' in node_dict:
                cmd += ' -r __node:=' + node_dict['name']
            if 'parameters' in node_dict:
                for param in node_dict['parameters']:
                    for key, value in param.items():
                        cmd += ' -r ' + str(key) + ':=' + str(value)
        return subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
    else:
        return False

node_dict = {
    'package': 'my_package',
    'executable': 'executor',
    'name': 'executor_test',
    'parameters': [{'test': 'test'}],
}
process = start_ros_node(node_dict)
```

Seems to work fine, you can then use `process` to terminate the nodes if needed

```
process.terminate()
process.wait()
```